# Matplotlib imshow ticks are wrong with negative values

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


a = np.random.randn(5,5)
plt.imshow(a)
plt.xticks(range(5))
plt.yticks([i-2 for i in range(5)])
plt.show()
```

results in

[image]

??

Also imagine I had 500 instead of 5 ticks, how could I pass the ticks but have less be displayed (for example every 10th)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `extent` parameter, and no need to use `xticks` or `yticks`:

```
plt.imshow(a, extent=(-0.5, 4.5, -2.5, 2.5))
```

Output:

[image]

Use [`MultipleLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) for your second question:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

a = np.random.randn(500,500)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.imshow(a, extent=(-0.5, 500.5, -250.5, 250.5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(25))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(25))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: what about if one using a pcolormesh? has same issue and doesnt seem to have `extent` arg?

Comment: That sounds like a great topic for a new question thread!